# How to make custom gaussian noise layer that imposing different stddev to each column of dataset in Keras?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I want to make gaussian noise layer of Keras that is imposing noise with different stddev level to each column of dataset. However, since I am not know much about coding stuffs, there is a big problem that I cannot solve it by myself.

With source code of Keras gaussian noise layer,

I made a code like below :

```
def call(self, inputs, training=None):

  def noised():
    temp=inputs
    for i in range(100):
      temp[:,i]=temp[:,i]+K.random_normal(shape= 
                    (len(inputs),1),mean=0.,stddev=self.stddev[i])
      return temp

return K.in_train_phase(noised, inputs, training=training)
```

However, it shows an error like :

```
 object of type 'Tensor' has no len()
```

I believe that the error comes from the different type of shape.

Because, the original code, which is like below :

```
 def noised():
    return inputs + K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(inputs),
    mean=0.,
    stddev=self.stddev)
```

is using symbolic type of shape(K.shape), and what I imposed is integer type of number(len()).

However, I have no idea the way to overcome the problem.

It would really be a great help for me if you give me some way to solve it.

Thank you so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's super late, but maybe it's still interesting for other people. I'm using Tensorflow 2.3.0 and I can just use the numpy slicing commands. So slice the tensor, apply the individual layers and merge them back together:

```
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,3))

x1 = GaussianNoise(0.1)(input[:,:,0:1])
x2 = GaussianNoise(0.2)(input[:,:,1:2])
x3 = GaussianNoise(0.3)(input[:,:,2:3])

x = Concatenate()([x1,x2,x3])
```